# how to share my DSl brodband to use in other laptop via my laptop wifi?

Tags: windows, networking

how to share my DSl brodband to use in other laptop via my laptop wifi ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to create an ad-hoc wireless network between the two laptops. How to do it depends on your operating system.